# Downloads an uploaded file from updates telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm using telethon for my telegram bot but I'm still learning how to use the library.

I want to download every file from the user that uploads a file to the bot. I'm using updates and my code look like this :

```
api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'
bot_token = 'xxx'

client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
          await event.reply('hi!')
```

"if a file uploaded to the bot, download the file". Do i need to create a new function or it can be inside that my_event_handler function? also I'm still confused on how to use the `download_file` or `download_media` to download the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to create a new function or it can be inside that my_event_handler function?

You can just add a few rows into your `my_event_handler`function. I'll show you how to do it.

```
api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'
bot_token = 'xxx'

client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage)
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
              await event.reply('hi!')
        file_path = 'PATH_WHERE_FILE_IS_TO_BE_DOWNLOADED'
        result = await event.download_media(file = filepath)
```

> `result` would return `None` if no media was provided, or if it was
>   Empty. On success the file path is returned since it may differ from
>   the one given.

Check out the docs for more, you got to check [download_media](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_media) and also [download_file](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_media)

Comment: the event.download_media or file was working fine, thank you. btw can i validate the file if more than 5 mb, the file will not downloaded?

Comment: @Aer0nux then please sign my answer as the correct one, btw Telegram will download and send the file that respect these limits: 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.